# Mac 10.8.3 MeCab Python "Symbol Not found" Error

Tags: python, mecab

I installed "https://code.google.com/p/mecab/downloads/list".

And

```
>>> import MeCab
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MeCab.py", line 26, in <module>
    _MeCab = swig_import_helper()
  File "/Users/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MeCab.py", line 22, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_MeCab', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_MeCab.so, 2): Symbol not found: __ZN5MeCab11createModelEPKc
  Referenced from: /Users/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_MeCab.so
  Expected in: dynamic lookup
```

Maybe RUBY user have same error.
http://www.sssg.org/blogs/naoya/archives/2183

But I don't know RUBY.
So I don't understand their fixed solution.

Plz, help me somebody~!

Comment: From the link you provided, that guy Naoya ran into errors while building the ruby-mecab binding, since the mecab lib itself was not being found. He had to hack the `extconf.rb` file to call `mecab-config --libs-only-l` to make sure that that the mecab lib would be found. Have you run into any errors when running `setup.py`?

Comment: When I command that "python setup.py install", I have no error. I tried this procedure in ubuntu, it has no problem. It's good work.
This problem is just in mac..

Answer (score 1):

When I tried to run the latest mecab-python-0.996 with python3 on my Mac OS X (Yosemite), I got the same error. But thanks to the following pages, by re-building the library, I could successfully do "import MeCab" in my application (but still get the same error running 'python3 -c "import MeCab"' on the command line).

http://ksmzn.hatenablog.com/entry/mecab-python3
http://d.hatena.ne.jp/yassuo_s/20110403/1301809955

$ wget https://mecab.googlecode.com/files/mecab-python-0.996.tar.gz

$ cd mecab-python-0.996

$ vi setup.py  (change cmd2 as follows for python3)

```
def cmd2(str):  
    return cmd1(str).split()
```

$ ls ./build

```
lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7   temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7
```

$ python3 setup.py build

$ ls ./build

```
lib.macosx-10.10-x86_64-3.4 lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7   temp.macosx-10.10-x86_64-3.4    temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7
```

$ sudo python3 setup.py install